# How to perspective project or warp an image onto a book cover?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, perspective

I'm trying to photoshop an image onto a book cover for a mockup, but am a bit confused about the best way to do this?

I'm using the 'Perspective' warp tool, but I'm finding it hard to:

1. Set the perspective exactly correct
2. Keep the image from being resized without respecting ratio

I seem to recall in the past being able to almost define a plane, throwing my image onto the plane and resizing/scaling it accordingly, whereas perspective warp confuses me because you aren't defining the plane of the object you want to map *onto*, but rather the object you want to map itself.

For example:
[image: Start]

Setting perspective layout
[image: Set perspective]

Warping
[image: Manually warping]
[image: Warping]

End
[image: End]

Is there a better way to do this? I find it very finicky to know if the perspective is actually correct without a lot of fiddling, and also the aspect ratio of the image is definitely off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I remembered what I was thinking of, the [Vanishing Point](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/vanishing-point.html) tool.

[image: Vanishing Point]